# Here I want that a no. which is multiple of 5 should be executed in 'if' but the no. which is not the multiple of 5 shouldn't execute, print 'else'

Tags: c, input, conditional-statements, output

Definition: Solving ATM problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    // your code goes here
    float x;
    float y = 2000;
    printf("Instruction: This ATM accepts values which are multiple of 5 \n");
    printf("Enter the amount to withdraw: \n");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    if (x / 5 && x <= y)
    {
        float z = y - x;
        float a = z - 0.5;
        printf("Your Transaction is successful\n\n");
        printf("Your Account Balance is %f\n\n", a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: %f\n\n", x);
        printf("Read the Instruction carefully\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please keep your title short to summarize the problem, and then ask the question in detail in the actual body.  Describe what's wrong with your program currently instead of essentially saying "fix it and deliver to my github plz".

Comment: Thanks For Your Suggestions, since it was my first time that I asked such a query, I will take care of it in the coming future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fmodf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) to check the remainder of two `float`s, an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 25.0f;
    float b = 25.1f;

    printf("%f divisible by 5 = %s\n", a, fmodf(a, 5.0f) == 0 ? "true" : "false");
    printf("%f divisible by 5 = %s\n", b, fmodf(b, 5.0f) == 0 ? "true" : "false");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
25.000000 divisible by 5 = true
25.100000 divisible by 5 = false
```

In your case:

```
if((fmodf(x, 5.0f) == 0) && (x<=y))
```